# replace spaces with "breakable" nbsp in html document

Tags: html, entity, spaces

I have an application where users can edit kind of templates (textarea). The resulting text is later showed as html, and pdf also generated from it.

Currently multiple consecutive spaces are shown as one space (this is html).

I have to change this, multiple spaces must be shown in the pdf and in the html.

My first thought was to use white-space pre-wrap.

BUT unfortunately there is a complicated processing involving xslts and other horrible things which I cannot change right now, and these prevents multiple spaces to "survive".

My second thought was to replace spaces with non-breaking space entities (nbsp).

BUT unfortunately that causes long lines not breaking at all (slide bars shown in browser, line overflows margin in pdf).

I thought to replace spaces with `<span> </span>` but that makes the html very long (If there's no better solution I'll do this probably).

So my question is: is there a "breakable" space entity which is preserved in html?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing spaces with 'nbsp' and 'zero width space' pairs seems to solve my problem.

```css
body {font-size: 64px;}
```

```html
<div>Here comes 5 spaces     . Html merges consecutive spaces, understood.</div>
<div>Here comes 5 'nbsp':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;. Not merged, fine.</div>
<div>Here comes 100 'nbsp':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;. They are not merged but they are also not breakable, which is not good in my case.</div>
<div>Here comes 100 'nbsp' plus 'zero width space':&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;&nbsp;&#x200B;. They are not merged and they are breakable.</div>
```